# Chart.js chart appears and disappears on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I searched through the stackoverflow for an answer and didn't get one so I thought I would ask incase anyone else is having a problem with it.

I based the chart off of an example https://travishorn.com/stacked-bar-chart-with-chart-js-846ebdf11c4e

The only change is i am getting the data from a ajax call instead of just having static data

The html/php:

```
 function addHeader() {
  echo <<< SUBHEADER
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Chart.min.js"></script>

SUBHEADER;
}
$d1 = isset($_GET['d1']) ? $_GET['d1'] : date("m/d/Y"); // default to today
$db = isset($_GET['db']) ? $_GET['db'] : 1; //Default to Cloud 1
$cd = isset($_GET['cd']) ? $_GET['cd'] : 1; //Default to two weeks before start
$cc = isset($_GET['campus']) ? $_GET['campus'] : false;

$campus_list = CampusList::GetCampBytype($db);


$cc_class = 'Cloud' . $db;

$stats = $cc_class::getPackagingReport($d1);
$test = Cloud::getStartDates();
?>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form id="chartdata" method="GET">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-autoclose="true" style="float:left;width:150px;margin-right: 15px;">
      <input name="d1" type="text" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $d1; ?>">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group" style="float:left;margin-right: 15px;">
    <select class="form-control" name="db">
      <option value="1">Cloud 1</option>
      <option value="2">Cloud 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group" style="float:left;margin-right: 15px;">
    <select class="form-control" name="campus">
      <option value="">Choose campus</option>
    <?php foreach ($campus_list as $campus) {
      if ($cc == $campus->campuscode) $selected = "selected";
      else $selected = "";
    ?>
      <option id="cc" value="<?php echo $campus->campuscode; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $campus->campusname; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="form-control" style="float:left;width:150px;margin-left:15px;margin-top:0px;" value="Submit" />
  </div>
  </form><br>

<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

The JS

```
<?php
      function addFooter() {
      global $d1, $db;
      echo <<< FOOTERSCRIPT
      <script>
      $("#chartdata").submit(function(){
        var cc = $('#cc').val();
        var test = "/sci_packaging_report_data.php?d1=$d1&db=$db&cc="+cc;
        console.log(test);

        $.ajax({
          url : "/sci_packaging_report_data.php?d1=$d1&db=$db&cc="+cc,
          type : "GET",
          success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            var dataset = [data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5]];
            console.log(dataset);

            var ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'bar',
              data: {
                labels: ['2 Weeks Before Start', 'Saturday Before Start', 'Saturday of Start Week', 'End of Second Week', '3 Weeks After Start'],
                datasets: [
                  {
                    label: data[0] + ' Packaging',
                    data: [data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5]],
                    backgroundColor: '#D6E9C6',
                  },
                  {
                    label: 'Expected Numbers',
                    data: [60,70,80,90,100],
                    backgroundColor: '#FAEBCC',
                  }
                ]
              },
              options: {
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
                  yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
                }
              }
            });

          }, //success function close
          error : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          }
        }); //ajax close
      });
      </script>
FOOTERSCRIPT;
  }
```

So the problem I have is when I submit the parameters the chart flashes for an instant and then disappears. I can see it has the correct heading but its too fast to see if the rest of the data populates.

I took the portion of code I need for the chart and placed it in a test file to see if it maybe other portions of my code was screwing it up and it did the same thing (flash for a instant and disappear)

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I wasn't passing e and using prevent default. So it was just refreshing and erasing my table.